# Injecting OData v4 into MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, odata

I am currently hoping someone adventurous may have tackled this obstacle,
as the current builds for MVC 6 running on ASP.Net v5.0 do not have any services I can find to load OData into the pipeline.  I invoke the app.UseMvc() and can construct convention routing, but cannot define any HttpConfiguration object in the new process.  I was really hoping to work with the combined MVC/WebApi in MVC 6, but OData v4 is a game changer.

If anyone has had experience and could point me in the correct direction, please advise:

It may not help greatly, but here is my Startup class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
using Microsoft.Data.OData;
// Won't work, but needs using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

namespace bmiAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {

            app.UseWelcomePage();
            app.UseMvc();

        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just as an aside, if any are reading wonder where System.Web.Http is, with MVC 6 the Owin context replaces that with Microsoft.Aspnet.Http.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 6 does not yet support OData. To host OData in ASP.NET I would currently recommend using ASP.NET Web API 2.x, which supports both OData v3 and OData v4.

If you want to use OData in an ASP.NET 5 app, you can use the [OWIN bridge](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Owin.IAppBuilderBridge) to host Web API 2.x on ASP.NET 5, but it still won't be using MVC 6.

You'd then have some code like this (based on the aforementioned bridge):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // Use OWIN bridge to map between ASP.NET 5 and Katana / OWIN
    app.UseAppBuilder(appBuilder =>
    {
        // Some components will have dependencies that you need to populate in the IAppBuilder.Properties.
        // Here's one example that maps the data protection infrastructure.
        appBuilder.SetDataProtectionProvider(app);


        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration(); 
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( 
            name: "DefaultApi", 
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", 
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } 
        );

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    };
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to get ahead at work enough to buy time for picking up more experience in build more middleware; everything I have seen from the new direction is invigorating!

This helped also, in case any may come across this page -- if you do not want to map all requests to managed modules (so you do not get into rewriting IIS), or if you want to use class libraries and still manufacture a nice small server factory for running HTTP layered OData v4.  Currently I have found more support on the OData4 round trip in .Net, and appreciate the good answer